# pthread-stubs for CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, drm, opengl

I try to install Mesa 7.8 for CentOS 5.
During installation of Mesa I required to install librdm, and during librdm (v. 2.4.19)  installing I got error about missing pthread-stubs:

```
checking for PTHREADSTUBS... configure: error: Package requirements (pthread-stubs) were not met:
```

When I try:
yum provides *pthread-stubs*
I get nothing
In other place I found that libxcb-devel is what I need, but yum not find this too.
During searching in Google, I found rpm's for Fedora only.

Any one know whether there is some packege which provides pthread-stubs for CentOS, or other, less expensive way to install Mesa?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to run:

```
yum install mesa*
```

This simply will install all necessary libraries.